# How to recall a value from an array in VBA

Tags: vba

Can somebody please help me understand why my value in an array is empty after I have assigned a value to it when I print it in the immediate screen?

```
Dim p, q As Integer
Dim MyArray3() As Variant
ReDim MyArray3(1 To 10000, 1 To 1)


p = 1
Do While Range("C" & p).Value < 2.05

   Debug.Print Range("C" & p).Value, p, myArray(5)
    MyArray3(p, 1) = Range("C" & p).Value
    q = q + 1
    p = p + 1
    Debug.Print MyArray3(p, 1)
Loop
```

Comment: Move the line incrementing `p` _after_ you print the value.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, sometimes coding makes me feel stupid.